# Laravel error "404 not found" pops up anytime I try to submit a signup form that I created

Tags: php, laravel, http-status-code-404

I am a few days into laravel and I'm being led by a tutorial. I was led to create a sign up and sign in form. The problem is, whenever I click the submit button after filling the signup form, I get a "404, not found" error. I have also run "php artisan route:list" on the command line and my signup route is listed there. The worst thing is that I have no idea where the error is coming from.

Here is the code:

```
WEB.PHP
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/



Route :: group (['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
   Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
   });
   Route::post('/signup', [
        'uses' => 'UserController@postSignUp',
        'as' => 'signup'
   ]);
    
});
?>
```

---

```
WELCOME.BLADE.PHP

@extends('layouts.master')

@section ('title')
welcome!
@endsection


@section ('content')
<div class = "row">
    <div class = "col-md-6">
        <h3> Sign Up </h3>
        <form action ="{{route ('signup')}}" method = "post">
          <div class = "form-group">
                <label for= "email"> your E-mail </label>
                <input class = "form-control" type="text" name = "email" id= "email">
          </div>
          <div class = "form-group">
                <label for= "first_name"> your first name </label>
                <input class = "form-control" type="text" name = "first_name" id= "first_name">
          </div>
          
          <div class = "form-group">
                <label for= "password"> your password </label>
                <input class = "form-control" type="password" name = "password" id= "password">    
          </div>
          <button type = "submit" class = "btn btn-primary">submit</button>
        <input type = "hidden" name = "_token" value="{{Session::token() }}">
        </form>
                
</div>
<div class = "col-md-6">
    <h3> Sign In </h3>
        <form action = "#" method = "post">
          <div class = "form-group">
                <label for= "email"> your E-mail </label>
                <input class = "form-control" type="text" name = "email" id= "email">
          </div>
          
          
          <div class = "form-group">
                <label for= "password"> your password </label>
                <input class = "form-control" type="password" name = "password" id= "password">    
          </div>
          <button type = "submit" class = "btn btn-primary">submit</button>    
        </form>
                
    </div>
@endsection
```

---

This is the UserController file guys

USER CONTROLLER.PHP

---

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\user;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class UserController extends Controller {
    public function postSignUp(Request $request){
        $email = $request ['email'];
        $first_name = $request ['first_name'];
        $password = bcrypt($request ['password']);
        
        $user = new user();
        $user -> email = $email;
        $user -> first_name = first_name;
        $user -> password = $password;
        
        $user -> save();
        
        return redirect() -> back();
        
        
    }

    public function postSignIn (Request $request){
        
    
    }

}


?>
```

---

Comment: Can you show UserController?

Comment: Route::post('url', 'rest of code')->name('signup');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things that could cause this:

1. The route doesn't exist - Unlikely, as you've checked your `route:list`
2. The route you are redirecting to doesn't exist - The typical response from a `POST` request to a controller is a `redirect()` to a view or route. It could be that this is where your error is occurring.
3. You have two or more routes which would correspond to the URL - This can happen by accident due to the order in which the routes are evaluated from top to bottom in your route files.

Answer (score 0):

if you try to build the url manually and put in browser to go to /signup what happens ? if u getting 404 although you hard typed the url in browser then u have something wrong in web.php another entry may be

Comment: It's the same thing, I'm still getting the same error

Comment: revise the web.php may be there is some entry invalid or doubled

Answer (score 0):

I solved it guys. I used command prompt to enter the code "php artisan serve --port= xxxx", xxxx being the numbers of the new port I connected laravel to and then I was able to recieve a stack trace on clicking the sign up button of the form I created. I saw where the error was. So I forgot a dollar sign in my UserController.php code. Thanks for your effort guys.